# split the `sentence` string into array of arrays based on `phrases` array

Tags: javascript

We have a sentence as a string and an array of some of the phrases in the string like this:

```
const sentence = "I told her your majesty they are ready";
const phrases= ["your", "they are ready"];
```

I want to split the `sentence` string into array of arrays in which each array has been spliced based on `phrases`.

The desired result would be this:

```
[ ["I told her"], ["your"], ["majesty"], ["they are ready"] ]
```

We split the 'I told her' into one array because we want to have 'your' in an individual and separate array (because 'your' is one of the phrases elements).

I used a for loop to substring the sentence by iterating through the phrases with no luck.

Comment: Why do you want to have 2d array with the nested array always containing one string? Also is the trimming of strings intentional?

Comment: I don't want a 2d array because I want to... I do want it because I need to :) Trimming of what... I don't understand?

Comment: The ouput of your input should be `[ ["I told her "], ["your"], [" majesty "], ["they are ready"] ]` (notice spaces in the tokens) if you don't want to trim your chunks. That's why I am asking if trimming is intentional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this. When you use a capture group in it, it will be retained in the result of a `.split()` method call.

Your example shows that spaces are to be trimmed in the result, so you could use `\s*` for that in the regular expression.

Also, `split("they are ready")` would include a final empty string in the returned array. If you don't want such empty results to be included, then apply a `filter` on the result, like so:

```js
const sentence = "I told her your majesty they are ready";
const phrases= ["your", "they are ready"];

// Build the regex dynamically:
const regex = RegExp("\\s*\\b(" + phrases.join("|") + ")\\b\\s*", "g");

let spliced = sentence.split(regex).filter(Boolean);

console.log(spliced);
```

NB: If your phrases contain characters that have a special meaning in a regex, then you should [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) those characters.

Comment: Nice!
I tried with "I told her your majesty they are ready to go to your castle where they are ready to fight" and it all works perfectly.